# What are the environment variables mandatory to connect to a DB via sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-home

What are all these parameters in sqlplus.

1. ORACLE_HOME
2. ORACLE_SID
3. TNS
4. SERVICE_NAME
5. DB Name

What are all the things I should ensure to connect to a DB via sqlplus. I'm getting different different errors in different times.

***Some are below:***

1. ERROR:
   ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
2. Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
   SP2-0667: Message file sp1.msb not found
   SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
3. SP2-1503: Unable to initialize Oracle call interface
   SP2-0152: ORACLE may not be functioning properly

Comment: Actually none is mandatory. But you get error if you set them wrong. Remove all of them and try again. However, it looks like you have a problem at your database.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to external DB, or trying to connect to your own(localhost)? Cause the error pattern indicates, that the problems is with DB itself.

Comment: Some environment variables are different between Windows and Linux.